# What specific files should be added to .gitignore for a Service Fabric solution?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

With Azure Service Fabric project builds creating/modifying xml files in my solution, what specifically should I add to my `.gitignore`? Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the Visual Studio gitignore settings from GitHub. There isn't really anything that Service Fabric or the Visual Studio tools for SF generate - that aren't build output - that you should ignore. The XML files that you see in Visual Studio (ApplicationManifest.xml, ServiceManifest.xml, Settings.xml, etc.) are all very much part of your application and services that should be checked into source control. These files shouldn't get modified on their own just by opening or compiling your projects.

EDIT: VS *does* modify some of the manifest files for certain project types, but regardless, those manifest files describe your applications and services and can be modified manually too, so they should get checked in to source control.

Comment: Our csproj files automatically include the property `UpdateServiceFabricManifestEnabled`, which updates the ServiceManifest.xml file on build. Which is helpful.

Comment: Yeah you're right, depending on the project type, Visual Studio will update the manifest files at certain times. Either way, those changes define your application/services so they should get checked in.

Comment: So really what I need to do is toggle my settings with my build scripts to manage my environments. We'll continue to check in our local settings, but those differ from other environment settings. Next step is to figure out how to better manage our environments. :)